# Print each value from terraform list variable

Tags: terraform

I have changed this datadog terraform module to support multiple slack channels, basically changed `var.alert_channel` from `string` to `list(string)` How would I print all the slack channels in the array in the last line of the message block?

```
    resource "monitor" "high_error_rate" {
      count = length(var.environment)
    
      name = "${var.name} (${upper(var.environment[count.index])}) high error rate"
      type = "log alert"
    
      message = <<EOF
      ${var.name} has increased error log rate throughout last 5 mins
    
      Environment: ${upper(var.environment[count.index])}
    
      @slack-${var.alert_channel}
      EOF
```

What would be the best way to print `@slack-${var.alert_channel}` for each channel in the list?

I looked into `count` and `for each`, but didn't found a working solution for this yet

Comment: Where do you want to print it?

Comment: I removed some parts of code, but basically this would be sent if some alert is triggered in datadog, like: notified [slack channels]

Comment: Your question config shows that `environment` was changed into a `list(string)`, but later in the question it is implied that `alert_channel` was changed into a `list(string)`. Which is it? Could you please add necessary details to the question to clarify the ambiguities?

Comment: No, the environment already was `list(string)`, the only change is that `var.alert_channel` has been switched to `list(string)` from `string` to support multiple slack channels. Here I need to print each of those channels in the list.

Comment: I think you need to use `for` expression to achieve this. Let me test out this scenario.

Comment: @vyt45 With the additional information, I can answer that you need to either 1. combine the `@slack-` into the variable elements values to then invoke the `join` function 2. use a `templatefile` instead of a multiline string for the `message` argument value. Your choice, but an answer can be written for either.

Comment: Thanks, I went with `templatefile` solution and it seems to work as desired